# when writing string to image, I get a long, narrow image - how break lines?

Tags: java, string, image

I'm trying to write strings to images, so it's harder to copy the text and run it through a translator.

My code works fine, but I get always a really long image - I rather would like to have a more readable box in where the string is written. My method "StringDiver" does add "\n" but it does not help when writing the string to an image.

Right now I get [this](http://i45.tinypic.com/260pt01.jpg) output.

Any hint what I could do?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class writeToImage {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String newString = "Mein Eindruck ist, dass die politische und öffentliche Meinung in Deutschland anfängt, die wirtschaftliche Zerstörung im Inland und in Europa zu erkennen, die auf einen eventuellen Zusammenbruch des Euro folgen würde.";
    String sampleText = StringDivider(newString);

    //Image file name
   String fileName = "Image";

    //create a File Object
    File newFile = new File("./" + fileName + ".jpg");

    //create the font you wish to use
    Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    //create the FontRenderContext object which helps us to measure the text
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

    //get the height and width of the text
    Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(sampleText, frc);
    int w = (int) bounds.getWidth();
    int h = (int) bounds.getHeight();

    //create a BufferedImage object
   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    //calling createGraphics() to get the Graphics2D
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

    //set color and other parameters
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(font);

   g.drawString(sampleText, (float) bounds.getX(), (float) -bounds.getY());

  //releasing resources
  g.dispose();

    //creating the file
   try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", newFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }

public static String StringDivider(String s){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    int i = 0;
    while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 30)) != -1) {
        sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();



}
}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to write strings to images, so it's harder to copy the text and run it through a translator."*  So run it through OCR 1st?  That should make it interesting to rip your stuff and translate it to Cantonese, not like those boring 'plain text' strings.  Excellent!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g.drawString(sampleText, (float) bounds.getX(), (float) -bounds.getY());
```

Split text and write every part to image.

```
Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(sampleText, frc);
int w = (int) bounds.getWidth();
int h = (int) bounds.getHeight();

String[] parts = sampleText.split("\n");
//create a BufferedImage object
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h * parts.length,   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

int index = 0;  
for(String part : parts){
    g.drawString(part, 0,  h * index++);
}
```

ex:

```
first part:  x=0 ; y=0
second part: x=0 ; y=5
third part:  x=0 ; y=10;
```

heightText = h

Comment: Many thanks Err for your fast response. But I have the same question. What is "heightText"? The code does not work properly - can I read heightText from bounds.getHeight()?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LineBreakMeasurer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html). The first code example in the Javadoc is exactly what you're looking for.